# How to run an anonymous function that was given as parameter

Tags: javascript

I know i can have a function as a parameter in javascript. I can also run that function that was given as a parameter. Here's an example:

```
function myfunction(param1, callbackfunction)
{
    //do processing here
    callbackfunction();
}
```

What if i wanna give an anonymous function, how will this run inside the outer function.

For example with a function like

```
setTimeout(function(){
})
```

How is this anonymous function directly run without a name?

Comment: Because in the settimeout code it receives a reference to that function as a variable, and then decides to run it, just like you do with your callback function. The only difference is you can't see the internal settimeout code to tell what it's doing. You're comparing apples and pears here...your example of settimeout code is equivalent to you writing `myfunction("something", function () { });` to call your function. Your first code snippet is equivalent to the innards of the settimeout function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a name to call a function. Names are only useful for use in a debugging tool (e.g. when examining a stack trace).

To call a function you need an expression that resolves as the function, which you can follow with `()`.

You're passing the function as the first argument to `setTimeout`, so it gets stored in the first parameter of that function. `setTimeout`'s internals then call it.

You do the same with your code, only it is the second argument.

```
myfunction("some param", function () { /* ... */ }) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this makes it clearer?

```js
function callFunction(param1, callbackfunction) {
  console.log('callFunction', param1)
  //do processing here
  callbackfunction(param1);
}

function myCustomCallback(param) {
  console.log('myCustomCallback', param)
}

setTimeout(callFunction.bind(this, 'one', myCustomCallback ), 1000)

setTimeout(callFunction.bind(this, 'two', function(p) {alert(p)} ), 2000)
```